# Gson can't detect the class variable

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android, gson

I used Rxjava with retrofit and also use Gson as parser.  my class has several field and the important field that i deal with is firstName, lastName, NationalCode. i don't know why when i get the result from the server I can't get the national code and it replace last name to national code variable. i also checked my network Api with postman and it gives me the correct result.
this is what everything that i did:

Profile Class:

```
package com.example.android.funnyapp.data.model;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Base64OutputStream;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

/**
 * Created by root on 6/9/17.
 */

public class Profile {
    @SerializedName("first_name")
    @Expose
    private String firstName;

    @SerializedName("last_name")
    @Expose
    private String lastName;



    @SerializedName("gender")
    @Expose
    private Boolean gender;

    @SerializedName("national_code")
    @Expose
    private String nationalCode;

    public String getNationalCode() {
        return nationalCode;
    }

    public void setNationalCode(String nationalCode) {
        this.nationalCode = nationalCode;
    }
    @SerializedName("profile_id")
    @Expose
    private String profileId;
    @SerializedName("user_id")
    @Expose
    private String userId;
    @SerializedName("avatar_url")
    @Expose
    private String avatarUrl;

    @SerializedName("username")
    @Expose
    private String userName;

    @SerializedName("user_type")
    @Expose
    private String user_type;

    public Profile() {
    }

    public String getProfileId() {
        return profileId;
    }

    public void setProfileId(String profileId) {
        this.profileId = profileId;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }



    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUser_type() {
        return user_type;
    }

    public void setUser_type(String user_type) {
        this.user_type = user_type;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }



    public Boolean getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(Boolean gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    private String base64;
    public String getImage() {
        return "data:image/png;base64,"+base64;
    }
    public String getAvatarUrl() {
        return avatarUrl;
    }

    public void setAvatarUrl(File avatarFile) {
        this.avatarUrl = getFileToByte(avatarFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    public static String getFileToByte(String path){

        try{
            InputStream inputStream=new FileInputStream(path);
            byte[] buffer=new byte[8192];
            int bytesRead;
            ByteArrayOutputStream output=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Base64OutputStream output64=new Base64OutputStream(output, Base64.DEFAULT);
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                output64.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            output64.close();
            return output.toString();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //encodeString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return null;

    }
}
```

and also my Edit profile:

```
public class EditUserSettingPresenter {
    View mView;
    private int mErrorCode;
    public  EditUserSettingPresenter(View view){
        mView=view;
    }

    public void updateProfile(String token,Profile profile){

        Observer<Response<Profile>> myObserver= new Observer<Response<Profile>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(@NonNull Response<Profile> profileResponse) {
                mErrorCode =profileResponse.code();
                switch (profileResponse.code()){
                    case 400:
                        mView.errorResult(404);
                        break;
                    case 401:
                        mView.errorResult(401);
                        break;
                    case 403:
                        mView.errorResult(403);
                        break;
                    case 404:
                        mView.errorResult(404);
                        break;
                    case 500:
                        mView.errorResult(500);
                        break;
                    case 201:
                    case 200:

                        mView.updateProfile(profileResponse.body());
                        break;

                    default:
                        mView.errorResult(-1);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                Log.d("ErrorMessage",e.getMessage());
                mView.errorResult(mErrorCode);
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {

            }
        };


        appService service;
        service= ApiUtils.getAppService();
        service.editProfile(token,profile)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(myObserver);

    }
    public interface View{
        void updateProfile(Profile profile);
        void UpdatePassword();
        void UpdateImage();
        void errorResult(int errorCode);
    }
}
```

my postman Result:

```
{
  "id": "3efc50ef-8766-4686-b3f3-c89272f6fe2d",
  "first_name": "hUSSEIN",
  "last_name": "Rezaii",
  "gender": true,
  "national_code": "99522555",
  "image": {
    "url": "/images/default/empty_profile.png",
    "thumb": {
      "url": "/images/default/empty_profile.png"
    }
  },
  "user_id": "1243b22d-ccb4-4589-a411-56ce633c87de",
  "created_at": "2017-06-09T19:19:03.057Z",
  "updated_at": "2017-06-16T08:13:29.958Z"
}
```

Comment: `avatar_url` that is missing in your json response

Comment: I want to update only 3 field not all of them

Comment: You Gson code looks fine at first glance. Try to log your response using Retrofit/OkHttpClient.

Comment: i logged retrfoti response that is in my observer onNext method, the profileResponse.body() method values. it give wrong data, i mean the lastname and nationalCode are same. in fact they shouldn't have to be same.

Answer (score 0):

May be the profile_id is not found. Check the difference from your class and the json from Postman.

This is lib you can use to replace gson parser.

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure but using Gson and retrofit, your fields should be made public ?

Try dropping the privates

Comment: Did you try doing some logs, dropping all the attibutes and adding them one by one to see if one in particular is causing the issue

Comment: And when working with Gson personnally I drop the accessibility (no public, no private) and give the class attributes the same name as the tags

Comment: I got log and in my presenter observer, the profileResponse.body() gives the wrong answer, it give nationalcode and lastname same name

Comment: and everything else is fine ?

Comment: it give wrong data, the lastname and nationalCode shouldn't be same. it doesn't give any error

Comment: Ok for these two but what about the rest ot the data ? Well it's all string so I guess you won't get any errors even if data get mixed up

Comment: why i get string for nationalCode

Comment: Well I guess because it is processed as a String : : 
  "national_code": "99522555", and private String nationalCode;